# How do I access file in my Grails app outside web-app Folder on a Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, grails-2.0

I have a Grails application that can upload images to my server. I want to have a separate folder on my server that is not inside my web-app folder, i.e., not part of the war file.

On my server I ran tomcat 7.

1. How can I access a folder like /home/serveruser/image from my Grails application?
2. What do I have to change in my Tomcat 7 configuration in order to get access to this folder?

Comment: did you try to use `File('/home/serveruser/image')`?

Comment: No, do I have to set access rights on tomcat?

Comment: No, you have to set access rights in your OS

Comment: So if the user that starts the tomcat server has full access to his home folder. In this case the app can access it too?

Comment: Which command should I use to access the file new File(grailsApplication.parentContext.servletContext.getRealPath(imageSource)) or grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource(imageSource).getFile()

Comment: you should use `File('/home/serveruser/image')` as it located in `/home/serveruser/image`

Comment: Grails and Tomcat don't even play a role in this.  Basic File IO applies.  Do what Igor said.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov if you post your comment as answer I can accept it